# how is data managed in social networking websites?

Tags: twitter, social-networking, google-plus

I have always wondered about the architecture of social networking websites like twitter,facebook,google plus. Just out of curiosity i want to know, how do they manage all those long and short posts(including images,web links,etc) with comments on them. Do they store them in database or in xml files or some mix and match? How do they actually manage such a big amount of data?

Thanks

Comment: maybe check the facebook engineering talks: https://www.facebook.com/Engineering/videos

Comment: i'hv checked fb engineering talks but its not what i am luking for. My curiosity is more regarding how posts and comments on them are stored in database or in some xml file and what will be the consequences of doing that? or there is some better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook gave a technical talk at IBM's Silicon Valley Lab earlier this year and talked about their use of Apache hBase and how MySQL didn't scale well enough for them. They did not dive deeply into the structure of the data, but rather the infrastructure that powered the system and how they focused on very high-speed read operations.

Generally scale and speed are a huge deal for sites as large as these and they rely heavily on sharded database structures with automatic redundancy built in to the system.  They typically do not use database concepts such as referential integrity or even defined schemas because they dramatically affect database performance. For Facebook, if I recall correctly, they basically stored JSON objects that described the data and could easily add new fields into the objects to support new data structures whenever necessary. Where if you did a column operation on a table of a huge scale and across many different independent machines it would be a nightmare to get them in sync and not to take the system totally offline.

The [HBase at Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/UsingHbase) has some interesting graphics and information that you might find helpful.